# CSS Image Height

Tags: html, css, sass

My div has a height of 105px.

My image inside the div has a height of 359px.

How can I override the size of the div so that the image doesn't cut off and the height of the image is full.

Many Thanks

Comment: Could you share the HTML? Your question is a bit vague.

Comment: background-size:100% 100%; or contain http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=contain

Answer (score 1):

Try using background-image on your div, than you can use CSS properties like `background-position`, `background-size`, `background-attachment`, to fit the image inside your `div`.

If you need examples search for `background-image` into e.g. w3school.